# Can I create 2 site columns that have the same name?

Tags: 2013, development, site-column

I need to create 2 drop-down lists site columns named security, but which contain different choices. One drop-down is used for manager sub site, while the other is used in staff sub site.

Now seems that I can not have 2 site columns with the same name. So currently I named the 2 columns as: "Manager Security" & "Staff Security". So is there a way to have duplicate names?

I have tried the following:-

1. I override the name at the list level. But when I add a new choice inside the column from the site collection level, its original name for example "Manager Info" will be displayed in the list again.
2. And of course I do not want to define these columns as list columns since I might need them on other sub-sites.

Can anyone help on solving this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi John, did u find the solution for this I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 5):

John, if you are creating the site columns from the visual studio use the DisplayName property of the field for your case

```
<Field
  ID="{2690E8BF-0801-408A-8445-93D816DF5D29}"
  Name="LastName"
  DisplayName="Last Name"
  Type="Text"
  Required="FALSE"
  Group="Custom Site Columns">
  </Field>

 <Field
  ID="{22E0D583-DC48-45C4-ADC7-098A7289A286}"
  Name="SomeLastName"
  DisplayName="Last Name"
  Type="Text"
  Required="FALSE"
  Group="Custom Site Columns">
  </Field>
```

DisplayName can be same for multiple site columns.

If you want to do it from the UI, it is not possible and SharePoint will show you

> The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved. Choose
>   another name.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: no i am using the UI to create the columns ..

Answer (score 1):

you an still create them on site-level using gui. However, initially they must have uniqe titles (because in the background the columns are created, and the internal names are set to the title you gave. Internal names cannot be changed and have to be unique.) After creation, you should be able to change the title in the gui and use them in the lists.

however, it is not useful to have different colums with same name (even if it is just a displayname).

Answer (score 1):

As i was facing the same issue today, i digged a little and instead of creating a new question i'd rather get this one answered ^^'. It seems that the only possible way to achieve this is by code (C# & visual studio) or use this little workaround that works just fine :

- Create your column with an internal name (you can always take a look at the following link for naming conventions but the internal name should always be different : [Link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Naming-Conventions-for-5b1c0a7a))
- Rename the column with the display name you want, but add a hard space at the end (alt + 0160), the space being trimmed by SharePoint when the column is saved. You can do this as many times as you need for columns that should have the same display name (i can see the need behind it, as long as you use content types to sort them it should be fine).

Comment: "ur column"? Should that be "your column" or "URL column"?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i meant your column, i will try to avoid shortcuts from now on